# How to have Cairo Dock auto-hide, then reappear when cursor moved near screen edge?

Tags: linux-mint, gui, panel, dock, cairo-dock

How can one configure Linux Mint Cinnamon and Cairo Dock to automatically hide the dock, but then have it reappear when the user moves the cursor to the bottom edge of the screen (display)?

This type of autohide functionality is built into Linux Mint Cinnamon's native panel as well as macOS (see
https://youtu.be/anZFf2B-nlM?t=40 - no affiliation, BTW, just a concise video demonstration), and Windows.  But the goal is to have this functionality with Cairo Dock.

I did find this old short video that appears to depict someone doing this along the left side of the screen, but there is no description of how it was accomplished: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyOQqSXUV9I

Please note that the overall goal is be able to use an application in a maximized window, and then quickly move the cursor to the bottom of the monitor to display the dock.

Comment: Assuming X11, you might be able to automate something using `xdotool` and its various sub-ommands. Use `behave_screen_edge` to do a `windowmap` on the dock to make it appear, and separately use `behave ... mouse-leave` on the dock window to do a `windowunmap`.